# How to display full SVN Log in Netbeans IDE

Tags: svn, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans-plugins

I'm using Netbeans 7.3.1 on Windows. Is it possible to display the FULL Subversion SVN Log?
I'm searching something like "TortoiseSVN -> Show Log" view.

It seems to be only possible to view the SVN Log of a single file.

UPDATE: There is also no such function in NetBeans 7.4

Answer (score 5):

For the whole project; `right click` on the `project name` in the Projects pane, then go to `Subversion->Search History...` In the opening window for the seach options enter nothing just press Search button at right below. For a specific period entering revision or date will be reasonable.

The history of a single file one can use following info:

In Netbeans, right click on the filename at editing pane. Then select 
History-> Show History

Another very handy option is :
  Right click on the file from projects pane or Editing pane-> Subversion-> Show Annotations

a few seconds later you will see the names of commiters of each line. When you come across the name you will see the commit log.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and slap me for my bad question. I want to view the full SVN Log of all commits, independent from a single file. I updated my question.